# Static noise in edge detection

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

Here's the function I'm using to create the edges:

```
def getSob(img, size):
    #sobel
    img_sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_8U,1,0,ksize=size)
    img_sobely = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_8U,0,1,ksize=size)
    x_filtered_image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img_sobelx)
    y_filtered_image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img_sobely)
    img_sobel = cv2.addWeighted(x_filtered_image, 0.5, y_filtered_image, 0.5, 0)
    return img_sobel, x_filtered_image, y_filtered_image
```

and here's the result I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gXJn.jpg

As you can see, there's quite a lot of static noise in edge image. How do I improve this?

Comment: maybe you have to use smoothing [Gaussian Blur](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_non_local_means/py_non_local_means.html?highlight=gaussian%20blur) before to apply Sobel filter.

Comment: You do not show the input image. So we have nothing to compare.

Comment: The input image is below the edge image. Anyways I followed Bilal's suggestions and found out that Gaussian Blur indeed helped decrease the noise (but only of kernel size greater than 9)